# Split ~200mb log4j log file by day

Tags: bash, text, awk, logfile

I have a log file formatted as follows and I want to split it into multiple files by day (ie. log-2017-10-2, log-2017-10-3 etc). I've seen people do it with awk but I'm not sure how to handle stack traces because java.io.Exception is a new line. Is there any convenient way to achieve this?

```
    2017-10-02 04:26:02,534 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    2017-10-03 04:26:02,543 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXX
    2017-10-04 04:26:02,544 INFO XXXXXXXXX
    2017-10-04 04:26:02,546 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    2017-10-04 04:26:02,549 INFO XXXXXXXXXXX
    2017-10-04 04:53:02,787 WARN class.class.class: [FetcherXXXXXX], Error in fetch XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    java.io.IOException: Connection to X was disconnected before the response was read
            at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    2017-10-05 04:26:02,549 INFO XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Final file contents will be:

```
log-2017-10-2:
2017-10-02 04:26:02,534 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX


log-2017-10-3:
2017-10-03 04:26:02,543 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXX

log-2017-10-4:
2017-10-04 04:26:02,544 INFO XXXXXXXXX
    2017-10-04 04:26:02,546 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    2017-10-04 04:26:02,549 INFO XXXXXXXXXXX
    2017-10-04 04:53:02,787 WARN class.class.class: [FetcherXXXXXX], Error in fetch XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    java.io.IOException: Connection to X was disconnected before the response was read
            at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

log-2017-10-5:
2017-10-05 04:26:02,549 INFO XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: ok, post the final files contents

Comment: Did you try `logrotate`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest posted final file contents for reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk --posix 'BEGIN{f="log-header"} 
     $1~/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/{f="log-"$1} {print > f}' log
```

if there are too many dates (corresponding to too many open files) you may need to close files at one point.  For few hundred it should work as is.

The initial log file (log-header) is set in case your log doesn't start with the checked regex.

Comment: `--posix` is gawk-only and only applies to a very old version of gawk. By using it you disable all of the other extremely useful gawk extensions (e.g. gensub()) so if you're just trying to turn on RE intervals in a very old version of gawk then you should use `--re-interval` instead of `--posix`. Also since that flag is gawk-specific you wont get a too many open files error when you use it.

Answer (score 2):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} /{ 
         if (fn && !a[$1]++) close(fn);
         fn="log-"$1 
     }{ print > fn }' logfile
```

- `/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} /` - on encountering line starting with date string
- `if(fn && !a[$1]++) close(fn)` - close the previous opened file descriptor for the previous "date"
- `fn="log-"$1` - constructing filename

---

Viewing results:

```
$ head log-*
==> log-2017-10-02 <==
2017-10-02 04:26:02,534 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

==> log-2017-10-03 <==
2017-10-03 04:26:02,543 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXX

==> log-2017-10-04 <==
2017-10-04 04:26:02,544 INFO XXXXXXXXX
2017-10-04 04:26:02,546 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXXX
2017-10-04 04:26:02,549 INFO XXXXXXXXXXX
2017-10-04 04:53:02,787 WARN class.class.class: [FetcherXXXXXX], Error in fetch XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
java.io.IOException: Connection to X was disconnected before the response was read
        &XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        &XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        &XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        &XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        &XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

==> log-2017-10-05 <==
2017-10-05 04:26:02,549 INFO XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for the hint. That was not the whole logic, now updated